# Java garbage collector on database connection

Tags: java, jdbc

A question regarding garbage collector.
If i have created database connection and performed some operations on databse and after that i have not used connection object for longer time can garbage collector frees my connection. I want this connection to be used later.

EDIT : just to confirm ,if i have created my connection is at context level of webapp then whats the case ?

Comment: thanks hardik for quick comment,just to confirm ,if i have created my connection is at context level of webapp then whats the case ?

Comment: Repeat after me; The GC collects garbage, the GC collects garbage. i.e. discarded objects, not objects you have reference to.

Comment: thanks peter i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you keep a *strong* reference to a `Connection` object then garbage collector will never touch your object and database connection will remain. Just remember it cannot be used by multiple threads.

On the other hand if you keep opened connection for too long some underlying resources (like TCP/IP socket) might get interrupted.

If you loose the last reference to a connection (by overwriting it or setting to `null`) garbage collector *will* release all Java objects associated with the connection and the connection itself. But it will not release the underlying database connection, hence you must always explicitly call:

```
connection.close();
```

Comment: Note: it is not only our own code which can reference a connection. E.g. if it is managed in a connection pool, the pool will keep a strong reference to it till the end of its lifetime.

Comment: It may depend on the driver implementation, that the garbage collection finalize closes the connection, but that is unreliable, so you should call close.  If the connection is idle too long, some driver implementations might timeout and close.

Comment: "But it will not release the underlying database connection", what exactly is the underlying database connection?

Answer (score 1):

JVM garbage collection in a nutshell: If you, or anyone else, has a reference to an object then the JVM is not allowed to garbage collect it. If you don't have a reference to it then the JVM doesn't *have* to garbage collect it until it wants to.

Answer (score 0):

The connection will not be garbage collected as long as you keep a reference to it. Theoretically you can therefore keep using it for as long as you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you are no longer referencing the connection object, then it is a member for garbage collection, but in no way you can guarantee that it will be garbage collected by gc. it depends entirely on gc.

If you want to use it in future, better make it a global object. so that your application will keep a reference and it will not be a member for garbage collection.

Comment: Using does not affect garbage collection. The only thing that matters is whether or not a reference to the connection exists. So, as long as you can call "connection.createStatement()" then the comnnection will not be collected.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I actually wanted to say no longer referenced, I will edit it. thanks @torben

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type of reference you have for your connection. If you have strong reference then it wont be garbage collected but if you have weak reference then it will be eligible for GC.

If it is held by a static or instance level, it wont be garbage collected.

But instead of holding to a database connection for long (considering every database has a limit on number of connection) you should release and reacquire as and when needed.

You should also consider using ConnectionPool for better connection management.